# Dynamic number value compare in Yup with react hook form

Tags: reactjs, yup

I have a number which i need to send from my component to Yup Schema.
This number needs to gets compared with the yuo schema object.

As you can see in below code: `childrenParticipants` should always be less than any dynamic value.

```
export const bookingsSchema = yup.object().shape({
  childrenParticipants: yup
    .number()
    .required('This Field is blank')
    .integer('This Field must be an integer')
    .min(
      0,
      'This Field must be greater than or equal to 0'
    )

    .lessThan(yup.ref( ** ANY DYNAMIC VALUE ** ))
});
```